# Get ID parse with Ajax to PHP from one DIV to another

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have 4 DIV which I want the First DIV to open the second on-click of it, the Second should open the Third DIV on-click of it and the Third DIV should open the Fourth DIV on-click of it. I used collapse to do this and at every point of clicking each of the DIV, I used AJAX to parse an ID to the next DIV that will be used to query the database to get lists of value.

Issues:
1 - When I click on the first DIV it doesn't collapse to show the next DIV but if I remove the data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#project_id_parse" from the First DIV and remove class="collapse" from the Second DIV it displays all the 4 DIV without clicking it.

2 - After removing the class="collapse" and data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#project_id_parse" and I click on the First DIV to parse the ID with AJAX it parses the ID to the Second DIV but when I click on the Second DIV to parse the ID to the Third DIV, the Second DIV ID affect all other DIV's instead of just parsing ID to the specific DIV.

Below is my code:

```
<?php
    $query_active = "SELECT * FROM  `table`";
    $result_active = mysqli_query($connLocal, $query_active);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result_active)){
        $active_numbering=0;
        while($row_active = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_active)){
            $active_numbering++;
            $project_id     = $row_active['project_id'];
            $project_name  = $row_active['project_name'];
            $project_type = $row_active['project_type'];
        ?>
        

<script>
    
$("#project_id_parse").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // <-------stop the def behavior here.
  var id = this.firstElementChild.href.split('=').pop(); // extract the id here
  $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "project_list.php",
    data: {id:project_id}, // now pass it here
    success: function(data) {

      $('#process_toggle').html(data); //copy and paste for your special case
    }
  });
});
</script>


<div id="project_id_parse"  data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#project_id_parse" ><a href="project_list.php?id=<?=$project_id; ?>" ><?=$project_name; ?></a></div>
                    <div class="td"><?=$project_type; ?></div>
                
    <?php
        }
    }
    ?>
<!----------------------- First DIV ends -------------------------------------->

<div id="process_toggle" class="collapse">


<?php

$project_id = $_GET["project_id"];



    $query_process = " SELECT * FROM  `ghantoot_process` WHERE project_id = '".$project_id."' " ;
    $result_process = mysqli_query($connLocal, $query_process);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result_process)){
        $NO=0;
        while($row_process = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_process)){
            $NO++;
            $name     = $row_process['process_name'];
            $process_id     = $row_process['process_id'];
            
            
        ?>

        <script type="text/javascript">
    
$("#process_id_parse").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // <-------stop the def behavior here.
  var id = this.firstElementChild.href.split('=').pop(); // extract the id here
  $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "project_list.php",
    data: {id:id}, // now pass it here
    success: function(data) {

      $('#activities_toggle').html(data); //copy and paste for your special case
    }
  });
});
</script>

<div id="process_id_parse"><a href="project_list.php?id=<?=$process_id; ?>"><?=$name?></a></div>

    <?php
        }
    }
?>                  

<!------------------- the Second DIV ends --------------------------->


<div id="activities_toggle" class="content">

    <?php

$process_id = $_GET["id"];

    $query_activities = " SELECT * FROM  `ghantoot_activities` WHERE process_id = '".$process_id."' " ;
    $result_activities = mysqli_query($connLocal, $query_activities);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result_activities)){
        $NO=0;
        while($row_activities = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_activities)){
            $NO++;
            $name     = $row_activities['activities_name'];
            $activities_id     = $row_activities['activities_id'];
            
            
        ?>

<script>
    
$("#activities_id_parse").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // <-------stop the def behavior here.
  var id = this.firstElementChild.href.split('=').pop(); // extract the id here
  $.ajax({
    type: "get",
    url: "project_list.php",
    data: {id:id}, // now pass it here
    success: function(data) {

      $('#task_toggle').html(data); //copy and paste for your special case
    }
  });
});
</script>


<div id="activities_id_parse"><a href="project_list.php?id=<?=$activities_id; ?>"><?=$name?></a>

    <?php
        }
    }
?>

<!------   Third DIVs ends -------------------->

<div id="task_toggle" class="collapse">


    <?php

$activities_id = $_GET["id"];

$query_activities = " SELECT * FROM  `ghantoot_task` WHERE activities_id = '".$activities_id."' " ;
    $result_activities = mysqli_query($connLocal, $query_activities);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result_activities)){
        $NO=0;
        while($row_activities = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_activities)){
            $NO++;
            $name     = $row_activities['task_name'];
            $task_id     = $row_activities['task_id'];
                
        ?>
    

<div class="td"><?=$name?></div>
                    
        <?php
        }
    }
?>
```

Comment: why are you using `$_GET` ?

Comment: To get the ID sent from the first DIV through AJAX to second DIV

Comment: It won't work like that, AJAX is Javascript that talks to PHP, it doesn't run the same way as PHP does. Simply just store your AJAX response in a variable and output it in the div with JS

Comment: Please can you guide me on how to achieve this?

Comment: `$('#process_toggle').html(data);` is doing exactly what it should be, you just need to pick out the actual data you need and show that in the place you need it. You're 90% of the way there

Comment: If you want more accurate help, show us what data you're working with, what the response is inside the `data` variable etc

Comment: I just update my code with the PHP data am parsing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a logical error in your JavaScript code:

```
var id = this.href.split('=').pop(); // extract the id here
```

In this context, `this` is the alias of the HTML element selected by JQuery based on the ID attribute `project_id_parse`. So `this` refers to the `<div>` element, not the `<a>` element as you would expect. `this.href` will be `undefined` and your Ajax request will not be triggered.

To fix, change `this.href` to `this.firstElementChild.href`.

Comment: Please I will like to ask a question and will be glad if you can help. I was able to use this to parse from a DIV to another but when I tried to use this to parse to another DIV the new ID affects others.

Comment: @mideveloper If you have another question that unrelated to this one, please create a new question. If not, update your question with more details and sample code. I will examine it.

Comment: I just update the code, am having issues as stated above.

Comment: @mideveloper Your problem is very complicated. It not only contains PHP code, but also JS code for Ajax events and click events. You cannot arbitrarily remove attributes such as `class`, `data-toggle`, or `data-target`, because it will mess with the JS/CSS code. Although you have added the information, I do not understand the logic of your program. I find the issues here are only JS / CSS related and not PHP related. You should use your browser's debugger to debug your JS code. You can read the article https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/